# Can I combine two photos to get a good image of a non-full moon?

Tags: hdr, night, astrophotography, dynamic-range, moon

Is there a good combo of longer exposure and shorter exposure that I can use to get two photos of the moon that I can then combine to show the sun-lit side and the earth-lit side together so I have one disk?

What software post production will I have to do to reduce the glare on the earth lit side that comes from the sunlit side etc?

(I am using Aperture 3 and a Nikon D90.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I recommend you take a look at my answer to another question about photographing the moon here:

[Best Settings for Nighttime Moon Photos](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/459/best-settings-for-nighttime-moon-photos/6816#6816)

As for your specific question, it would probably be fairly difficult to get two shots that you could merge together without a tracking mount. As such, my first recommendation is to either buy an equatorial tracking mount, or if you have a friend who has one, see if you can borrow it. With a tracking mount, you should be able to get the necessary exposures at low ISO without any blur from the motion of the moon, which should result in a decent combination.

If you do not have access to a tracking mount, the best I can say is use the chart from my other answer linked above, and try to keep your exposure times as minimal as possible. A camera with very good high-ISO performance will make it easier to get a shot of earthglow with a short exposure, without losing too much detail. You might want to use ISO 3200 if you have it. Noise is a real moon detail killer, since your signal-to-noise ratio is pretty low to start with. Using higher ISO's and keeping exposure time faster than 1/15th of a second should do it, but you will experience some problems with noise.

Comment: I will have to get the tracking mount. My dad has one that I should be able to borrow for a while. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you're willing to do a lot of post-processing work, you can also do an [exposure stack](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8092/378) of shorter frames. Increase your ISO, take shorter exposures without the tracking mount, and align/combine them afterwards.