# How can I get good motion shots (long exposure) of the sea in daylight?

Tags: shutter

I have tried using my Nikon D5200 in aperture mode with a standard 50mm F1.8 lens at F16 with 2 filters, a Hoya circular Polariser + a ND4. I just can't get the shutter speed slow enough in fairly bright sunshine. 1/8 & 1/4 best. I use ISO 100 though the Nikon changes this to ISO 200. How can I get an exposure of several seconds? Any help gratefully received. Thanks. Roger.

Comment: duplicate - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42981/is-it-possible-to-take-a-long-exposure-photograph-during-daytime

Comment: At face value the question looks the same, but the earlier question is concerned with allowing details of the moving objects to show up. This question is concerned with blending the moving objects to eliminate specific details.

Answer (score 3):

You really only have a few options. Basically, it's all about shutter speed and reduced light, so you can:

1. Get a stronger ND filter. The "[Big Stopper](http://www.leefilters.com/index.php/camera/bigstopper)" by Lee is such an option, but even welders glass can do it. You can also stack filters, but I would tend to a single filter first.
2. Stop the lens down even more which will increase softness, but since you're actually looking for that in a way, it's less an issue.
3. Shoot in less bright conditions.
4. Bracket the scene with a sequence of faster shots and then [stack them](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27528/can-stacking-multiple-exposure-images-in-post-processing-give-the-same-effect-as?rq=1) to simulate the long exposure.